# VS2010 Profiler Cannot Locate Symbols

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, profiler

I have a C# console project that references a C# class library project in the same solution.  When using the VS2010 Profiler (launched with ALT-F2), I can see timing for methods in both the console project and class library project, but the source code for the class library project is unavailable.  Instead, I receive the error message:

> "Source code not available. You may not have the appropriate symbol
>   paths."

It looks like symbols for the class library project were loaded:

```
Loaded symbols for C:\...\MyApp\MyAppConsole\bin\Debug\MyAppConsoleApp.exe.
Loaded symbols for C:\...\MyApp\MyAppConsole\bin\Debug\MyAppClassLib.dll.
```

Also, Tools / Options / Debugger / Symbols says it's configured to automatically load symbols for all modules except excluded, and the excluded list is empty.

What else can I check or do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:  [Source code not available. You may not have appropriate symbol paths or there was error loading symbols.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vstsprofiler/thread/e8a760cb-c4c7-449f-b0ad-13aa614ca2f8)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.